# Obfuscate data in SQL and decrypt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, encryption

I have some large data sets stored in multiple SQL databases than contain PII regarding customer information. Nothing is super sensitive such as credit cards but it contains names, email addresses, and personal preferences. Email addresses from these sources are sometimes attached to links so that when someone clicks on a link we can use JavaScript on the site to pull that personal profile and configure certain aspects of the site based on their preferences. JavaScript is required because of interfaces with 3rd party JavaScript libraries.

Google prohibits PII in URLs for GA and other tools, so we need to sanitize the email address parameter. Our plan is to create another column in our databases that is an obfuscated version of the email address, something we can create using SQL, and also something we can decrypt with JavaScript on the site to allow the current preference systems on the site to work without modification. We aren't aiming for a secure algorithm, but something to satisfy Google's PII terms and the technical restraints in place.

Comment: If you have the data stored in database.... why not use the table PK and make an internal (and hidden) request instead of inserting the email in the url?

Comment: The _normal_ way to do this is to send up the `Id` of the user, typically a GUID

Comment: On the JS end of this we don't have access to the database, so we can't associate this way. Sorry if I didn't make that clear. The database systems and JS end aren't linked in that direction.